# Double alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to do some validation with jQuery. When I create errors for each field I get 2 messages in the alert. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/262eLfr7/).

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}


$("#submitButton").click(function(){

      var mesajEroare = "";

      /* verifica daca email-ul este true */
      if(isEmail($("#email").val()) == false) {
        /* arata mesaj eroare */
        mesajEroare += "<p>Email-ul introdus nu este valid</p>";
      }

      /* verificare nr telefon daca este numeric */
      if($.isNumeric($("#telefon").val()) == false){
        /* arata mesaj eroare la telefon*/
        mesajEroare += "<p>Numarul de telefon introdus nu este valid</p>";
      }

      alert(mesajEroare);

});
```

Comment: You only want 1? Maybe you need to do `mesajEroare = ` instead of `mesajEroare +=`

Comment: Thank you! have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are alerting with or without and error, because you wrote the alert function just outside, you should use :

```
  function isEmail(email) {
      var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
      return regex.test(email);
  }

  $("#submitButton").click(function(){

  var mesajEroare = "";
  var fieldMissing = "";

  if($("#email").val() == ""){
    fieldMissing += "<p>email</p>";
  } else if (isEmail($("#email").val()) == false) {
    mesajEroare += "<p>Email-ul introdus nu este valid</p>";
  }

  if($("#telefon").val() == ""){
    fieldMissing += "<p>telefon</p>";
  } else if ($.isNumeric($("#telefon").val()) == false){
    mesajEroare += "<p>Numarul de telefon introdus nu este valid</p>";
  }

  if($("#password").val() == ""){
    fieldMissing += "<p>parola</p>";
  }

  if($("#passwordConfirma").val() == ""){
    fieldMissing += "<p>confirma parola</p>";
  } else if($("#password").val() != $("#passwordConfirma").val()){
    mesajEroare += "<p>Parola nu este la fel</p>";
  }

  if(fieldMissing != ""){
    mesajEroare += "Nu ati completat urmatoarele casute" + fieldMissing;
  }

  if (mesajEroare != "") { // if found an error or more
    console.log(mesajEroare);
  }

});
```

Comment: Or you could check if the is a message instead of adding another variable to count messages?

Comment: i did how you said and i made a new error for fields but look the errors from email and number phone is still coming in my alert... (i did an alert for empty fields)    https://jsfiddle.net/262eLfr7/2/

Comment: @CIonut Check out this fiddle, it has the answer : https://jsfiddle.net/262eLfr7/4/

Comment: No it's working, I just replaced alert with console.log, try replacing it back and see.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the slightly unrelated answer but, if you want to have more than one error message, maybe you want to use the newline instead of the `<p>` tag.

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    var message = '';

    if (!isEmail('notAnEmail')) {
        message += 'Email not valid\n';
    }

    if (!$.isNumeric('boom')) {
        message += 'Phone number not valid\n';
    }

    if (message) {
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

And if you really do only want one error at a time, and you use `=` instead of `+=` you will only get the last error message in your alert.

Comment: I paid on udemy complete web dev and at validation is doing with this but i am getting double errors and him not...i can`t understand.(Thank you for help).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are appending strings which means the initial string `mesajEroare = ""` ends up with two strings if the conditions are `true`.

Based on what you want you should use `=` only instead of `+=`.

Comment: Thank you! have a nice day too!

Comment: But what if the user inputs 'dd' for email and 'aa' for telephone, then both errors should be printed.

Comment: In that case you should create an array with messages and do a loop on the array and show every message separated. The answer is specific to the asked question.

Comment: is to heavy for me with loops i am at beginning i will do it later thanks anyway for advices.